# Preg_replace to insert string before number

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

How do you insert a string before a number?

I have the following Wordpress function:

```
get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'level', '', ', ', '' )
```

This function outputs numbers like so:

```
<a href="#">1</a>
```

or, if there is more than one entry in the database:

```
<a href="#">1</a>, <a href="#">2</a>
```

How can I insert "level " before the number? so that it looks like this:

```
<a href="#">level 1</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="#">level 1</a>, <a href="#">level 2</a>
```

Comment: Do you have to use `preg_replace`? It seems like you've already chosen your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply match the number. In a regex `\d+` can be used for decimals.

```
 $text = preg_replace('#>(\d+)<#', '>level $1<', $text);
```

And you can just use `>` and `<` anchors. Here `$1` reinserts the found decimal.

Answer (score 4):

[Function Reference/get the term list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

the worpress manual tells you exactly how.

i don't use wordpress but found it by goggling "worpress get_the_term_list"

Comment: I have read the codex and numerous tutorials. However, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this in my specific case (which I won't go into here) hence my asking how to use preg_replace instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do it:

```
get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'level', 'Level: ', ', ', '' );
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list

**Edit:**

Edit `get_the_term_list` in `wp-includes/category-template.php` to

```
/**
 * Retrieve a post's terms as a list with specified format.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param int $id Post ID.
 * @param string $taxonomy Taxonomy name.
 * @param string $before Optional. Before list.
 * @param string $sep Optional. Separate items using this.
 * @param string $after Optional. After list.
  * @param string $beforeEach Optional. After each term.
 * @return string
 */
function get_the_term_list( $id, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '', $beforeEach = '' ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );

    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) )
        return $terms;

    if ( empty( $terms ) )
        return false;

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
        if ( is_wp_error( $link ) )
            return $link;
        $term_links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">'. $beforeEach . $term->name . '</a>';
    }

    $term_links = apply_filters( "term_links-$taxonomy", $term_links );

    return $before . join( $sep, $term_links ) . $after;
}
```

Usage:

```
get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'level', '', ', ', '', 'Level: ');
```

Comment: This does not do what I want it to do. It places "Level" before the "<a href"

Comment: @user1444027 I added a edited function that will do just what you need

Answer (score 0):

Test these. You might need to tweak the offset, pos numbers. This will get you 99% there.

$numPos = strpos($string, "1");

$firstStr = substr($string, 0, $pos);
$secondStr = substr($string, $pos);

$newStr = $firstStr . "level" . $secondStr;